# S3 notification in Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, spring-boot, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-sns

My Spring boot application in Amazon Beanstalk need to re-load data stored in S3 whenever the file in S3 is updated. I was trying to figure out how to use Simple Notification Service (SNS) to trigger the reload. I looked at several examples ([here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/s3-event-notification/), [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/using-awssdkjava.html), and [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.managing.sns.html)) but everywhere the examples just explain how to send an email on notification. Nowhere can I find an example of how to use SNS in a spring boot application.

With the examples, I can do the following.

```
// instantiate the client
AmazonSNSClient snsClient = new AmazonSNSClient(new ClasspathPropertiesFileCredentialsProvider());                                 
snsClient.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1));

//subscribe to an SNS topic
SubscribeRequest subRequest = new SubscribeRequest(topicArn, "what_should_I_write_here?", "and_here?");
snsClient.subscribe(subRequest);

// don't know how to receive the alert now
// I want to call a method called loadData() when I receive a notification. How do I write that logic?
// I don't see any method in AmazonSNSClient which resembles getnotified() or similar.
```

Comment: How about you reverse it and have your application to check on those files?

Comment: @WayBehind are you talking about polling the files? That won't be a good architecture. Also, each poll to S3 incurs a cost.

Comment: I got around this issue by not using SNS (or SQS) at all. I set up an end point which when called would trigger a reload of data.
The script which downloads data to S3 now calls this end point after the download is complete. This ensures that the beanstalk application will reload the data.
This is not the exact solution I was seeking but still unblocks me. Answers to the original questions are still welcome.

Comment: Actually, thinking further, the answer to the original question would be to configure the S3 bucket to call this "trigger" end point once the download is complete.